Что подразумевается под object identity в пункте 5.2.2.4 стандарта ISO 9899:2024?
Цитирую стандарт:

Value computation for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the designated object.

value computation - вычисление значения, отделённого sequence point.
lvalue - это то, что стоит слева от оператора присваивания =.
identity - больше подходит "принадлежность".
object - есть понятное определение в начале стандарта.
designated - обозначенный (то есть, отдельный, получаемый результат текущей sequence point?).
Правильно ли я понимаю, что object identity - это соотнесение вычисленного значения и его места подстановки в выражение expression в общем случае, когда каждому identity соответствует своё место в порядке value computations конкретного evaluation?
